# SQLSTATE[42000] Error

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am working with database using PHP Data Objects(PDO) and I use try-catch block. I have the following code in my try block

```
    $name=$email=$subject=$message="";
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
    }
            $servername = "//I have some IP Here";
            $username = "//somuser";
            $password = "//somepassword";
            $dbname = "lifeimpu_userrequest";
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$lifeimpu_userrequest", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ContactUs(name, email, subject, message) VALUES ($name, $email, $subject, $message);";
        $conn->exec(sql);
        echo "Data Submitted Successfully";
```

I don't know why I always get

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sql' at line 1

It's appear just after execution of **$conn->exec(sql);**. The execution jumps directly to catch block.

I tried to executed these SQL in phpMyAdmin and it's working fine. I don't know why it does not work here in the code.

Comment: $name, $email, $subject, $message are strings, you need ' sign for strings

Comment: Already add ' ' but still doesn't work

Comment: try `$conn->query($sql);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your query like this,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ContactUs` (`name`, `email`, `subject`, `message`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '$message')";
```

and you missed `$` in

`$conn->exec($sql);`

Comment: i think this should helps